# how to create plugin single licence only

Tags: licensing

I have a question how to create activation key ?
I want to build a premium plugin but don't know how to make it for single license only, there are any way to do this ? any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do so, using an licence Server. The Plugin / The Theme sends an licence-code (md5 on the wordpress-url) each hour to that Server and check whether the licence-code is valid or not (also get some remote Settings, if you have multi-mode-licences (Basic, Standard, Extended) or so) and if it's not valid, the plugin stops working / the theme just Displays an maintenence-page.

May this is an way for you to do what you are planing to do.

Comment: awesome answer but i afraid some advance developer can remove the license. or MD5 setting and use as free ...

Comment: Jep, that could possibly be, but through licensing your PHP-code you can discard changes, so it will be illegal for manipulating the check.

Also you can try to write a Little bit of ugly code, so that there is a Chance to make him just remove one check-call but not all of them.

And then on the licence-Server you can Register each Domain wich requests an licence, and if the page stops asking for some days / weeks, you can control it maually, if your plugin is in Progress on that page or not.

Comment: May this discussion is interesting for you (and me, because what you asked is an fact, wich I have to read about next week, I still have the same Problem as you ^^)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157425/license-and-protect-php-script